# Printing PDF with phantom js - @page rule not working

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, printing, phantomjs

We're using the phantom JS to print out PDF from web pages (intranet site). My issue is not with the whole styling but just with the @page rule. None of the styles within the @page rule are applied.

Do you have any idea what this could be?

```
@page {
    size: auto;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 10mm !important;
    page-break-before: avoid;
    border: none !important;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;

    @top-left-corner {
        content: ""; /* has to be specified! */
        background-color: rgba(42, 201, 80, 0.220);
        border-bottom: solid green;
    }
}
```

Comment: hope you are using css3.Can u please specify browser

Answer (score 4):

[image: Browser support manual]
As the shown image describe the browser support for the @page.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a problem with your CSS, but perhaps it's contained within a stylesheet that is set to media `screen` already, in which case it will be ignored.

When you import your stylesheet make sure you use media type `print` or `all`

`<link href="main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think that when exporting to PDF, phantomJS automatically adds the @media print class which may override many of the css rules you set for the @page.